# Generate classes from access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

Is there an easy way to generate classes in visual studio from an access database? Something similar to `Entity Framework`?

If not what would be the easiest way, I have multiple forms where all the code is written and I need to create classes.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of. The *DataTableAdapter* comes close. If you create a connection to the database, it's a drag-n-drop process to pull the tables you need into the design pane. From then on, all (and the associated queries you may create) are accessible as objects with strong typing and other features.

It is much less sophisticated than the *EF* but keeps you off the primitive *SqlCommand* stuff.